# Samsung Notebook 9 Pro (NP940X5N-X01US) failed to resume from suspend under Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, laptop, samsung

Graphic Card: Radeon RX 540 2G

- Steps to reprodece:

  1. Close the lid and wait for the laptop to suspend
  2. Reopen the lid
- Expected behaviour:
  The laptop resumes working
- Current behaviour:
  The laptop does power on, CPU fans running but screen has no output, completely blank.

Having trid to install laptop-mode and enabled it but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the screen that remains shut off? This is what I have experienced a few times with 16.04 on two different machines. Try to lighten it up with the usual screen brightness `Fn` keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with the same laptop in 18.04. Downloading the proprietary AMD drivers from https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx fixed it for me but did dramatically reduce my battery life. I haven't figured that one out yet.